# If $\lim \limits _{x \to x_0} (f(x) + g(x))$ and $\lim \limits _{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exist, does $\lim \limits _{x \to x_0} g(x)$ also exist?

Tags: calculus, limits

If $\lim \limits _{x \to x_0} (f(x) + g(x))$ and $\lim \limits _{x \to x_0} f(x)$ exist, does it mean that $\lim \limits _{x \to x_0} g(x)$ also exist? If the first limit exists it can split into $L_1 + L_2$, but if $L_1$ is the limit of $f$ then it must mean that the limit $L_2$ of $g$ exists, right?

Comment: We have $g(x)=(f(x)+g(x))+(-f(x))$. Then use a theorem you have probably already proved.  The limit of $-f(x)$ is the negative of the limit of $f(x)$, and the limit of a sum is the sum of the limits.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use $g(x)=(f(x)+g(x))-f(x)$

Answer (score 1):

If those limits are finite, yes. It's also straightforward to see it.

Else no.
Try
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} x + \sin(x)$$

Comment: But those limits don't exist - you could say they go to infinity but there's no number L such that the functions get arbitrarily close to L.

Comment: An "infinite limit", while slightly improper, is well defined. In high school conventions if you answer "does not exist" to such a question you get a bad grade, even though it's technically correct to say "it has no limit in $\mathbb{R}$".
Hence my "if those limits are finite".

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that it's well defined -  it :doesn't really 'exist' in the same way and I wouldn't intepret "$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists" as including the possibility of infinite limits.

Comment: I wouldn't either in any advanced context, but you can't really be sure here. I've seen many HS textbooks who say "the limit can be finite, infinite or nonexistant".
Anyway, I believe the answer is clear enough! Good day